# Can Standard Loopholes be featured?

Tags: discussion

Our [Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) meta post is extremely helpful for simplifying challenges, and every time I post a challenge, I have to go look up the link for new users who might be unaware of it. Can we feature it permanently on meta since it is so useful?

Answer (score 8):

## No

Permanently featured posts aren't supposed to exist; Community removes the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) once a month. We make an exception for the sandbox and manually re-feature it each month, but the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) will have to do for everything else. The main reason for this is that there's a limited amount of vertical space in the side bar. Sometimes, when there are featured posts on Mother Meta or blog posts, not even a single one of our *Hot Meta Posts* is visible.

I'm not saying that a little extra visibility would hurt for the standard loopholes, but even if there were space for more featured posts, there are others I consider more valuable for new users, such as our policy about invalid answers, defaults for I/O, and things to avoid when writing challenges. These threads are important for *all* new users; the standard loopholes are only relevant for people who try to cheat.

Comment: I agree with you, that makes sense, but I still wish there was a page that held links for all of those pages.

Comment: @tfbninja, https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+policy ?